# Mask UIView with UIImage b/w iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview, uiimage

I'm developing a iOS app for iPad. I'd like to mask a UIView with an image in black and white. So the black part of the image is what you can see of the view.

If tried different codes like one below, but they don't work...

```
UIImage *_maskingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadmask.jpg"];
CALayer *_maskingLayer = [CALayer layer];
_maskingLayer.frame = vistafunda.bounds;
[_maskingLayer setContents:(id)[_maskingImage CGImage]];
[vistafunda.layer setMask:_maskingLayer];
vistafunda.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

They ipadmask.jpg is that: [image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apple documentation about CALayer `mask` property:

> An optional layer whose alpha channel is used as a mask to select
>   between the layer's background and the result of compositing the
>   layer's contents with its filtered background.

So you should fix the alpha channel of you image. Black pixels should be opaque and white - totaly transparent.